# Vim hanging after parsing .vimrc (even a blank one) file on Solaris 10

Tags: vim, solaris, tcsh

I am having a problem with vim 7.2 hanging (for about 10 seconds) after it parses the .vimrc file.  I had a similar issue in the past with tcsh on linux, but it was resolved by setting `TERM` to `xterm-color`.  The same does not resolve the issue here.  Any idea what may be causing this?

```
$ env
USER=redacted
LOGNAME=redacted
HOME=/home/redacted
PATH=redacted
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/redacted
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
TZ=redacted
LC_COLLATE=C
SSH_CLIENT=redacted
SSH_CONNECTION=redacted
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/11
TERM=dtterm
HOSTTYPE=sun4
VENDOR=sun
OSTYPE=solaris
MACHTYPE=sparc
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/redacted
GROUP=redacted
HOST=redacted
REMOTEHOST=redacted
QUOTA_CHECKED=1
WHOAMI=redacted
HOSTNAME=redacted
EDITOR=vim
PRINTER=redacted
INFOPATH=/software/gnu/gcc/2.8.1/sun4os5.10/info:/software/gnu/sun4os5/info:/software/gnu/emacs/20.3.1/sun4os5/info:/software/gnuish/sun4os5/info:/usr/local/gnu/info
MANPATH=/software/gnu/gcc/2.8.1/sun4os5.10/man:/software/gnu/sun4os5/man:/software/gnu/emacs/20.3.1/sun4os5/man:/opt/rational/clearcase/doc/man:/usr/openwin/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/dt/man:/software/gnuish/sun4os5/man
H_ARCH=sun4
H_ARCHOS=sun4os5
H_ARCHOS_SUB=sun4os5.10
H_OSTYPE=SUNOS
H_OSREV=51000
T_ARCH=sun4
T_ARCHOS=sun4os5
T_ARCHOS_SUB=sun4os5.10
T_OSTYPE=SUNOS
T_OSREV=51000
X11HOME=/usr/local/x11/sun4os5
OPENWINHOME=/usr/openwin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/dt/lib:/usr/openwin/lib
MOTIFHOME=/usr/dt
XINITRC=/usr/openwin/lib/Xinitrc
GCC_REV=281
```

Comment: How long does it take to read the file normally? `time (cat ~/.vimrc > /dev/null)`

Comment: Try running vim under the `truss` command, which shows which system calls the program is making, along with their arguments and return status.  I've had good luck with that approach in similar situations -- it could be something like an NFS server timing out, which will be obvious from the truss output.

Comment: @Jim Lewis

Thanks!  Turns out it was trying to connect to a display.

Comment: Why was it trying to connect to a display while you haven't a DISPLAY variable set ?
Also why "PATH=redacted" ?

Comment: 1. Not sure.  2. There was stuff I would rather keep to myself in my path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a `vim -X` make any difference (as I suspect you're not running gvim) ?

Otherwise, a lot of plugins may cause this. Or plugins that hang on some operations.

Comment: Well holy crap.  Truss showed that it was timing out trying to connect to an X server, and -X fixed it.  I will amend my cshrc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting vim with `-u NONE` to disable reading `.vimrc`, `-U NONE` to disable `.gvimrc`, and the `--noplugin` option disables loading of plugins, see if this helps.

Comment: Tried that.  Turns out that it was trying to connect to an X server.  Thanks SO!